# Perl Script: Neet to write a pattern based script to replace the values using perl

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a test file which contains many urls. All i have to do is writing a pattern based perl script where ever i see **values** need to change as **SSSS** in the url (value=combination of upper case, lower case, numerics and special characters).

In that file where ever i see numbers i changed it to NNN using below script.

```
perl -pe 's/(\\/\\d+\\/)/\\/NNN\\//g' | perl -pe 's/(\\/\\/d+$)/\\/NNN/g'
```

I tried below script to change values as SSSS, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
sed -E 's#(.\*/(code|catalogue)/)\[^/\]\*#\\1SSSS#' file
```

Using above sed i can change some, but it will change some i never want to change. for example you can see this

`/goods-catalogue-service/v1/api/catalogue/NNN/code/ahvs123/categories`

`/auction-catalogue-service/v1/api/catalogue/CAT_CMC_KGF_10/catalogue-item/search-category-item`

if you observe both above lines. I want to change ahvs123 and CAT_CMC_KGF_10 as SSSS. In this case in the first line after catalogue where NNN is there that is also changing as SSSS which i dont want.

So only i am preferring perl script.

```
perl -pe 's/\[\[A-Za-zA-Z0-9\_\\-\]+/SSSS/g'
```

i tried this one also but it is changing entire line as SSSS.

Can some one suggest me a script. I attached a file for your reference.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Isa34L7hWju5BWsTWOItftwT71zMJsQN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't add material to the question in a link to an external file. You should include some test cases: Input with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative **look-ahead** `(?!)` of regex.

```
open(TEXT, "<test.txt");
my @lines = <TEXT>;
close(TEXT);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/\/catalogue\/([^\/]+)\/(?!(code\/|.+?\/code\/))/\/catalogue\/SSSS\//;
    $line =~ s/\/code\/([^\/]+)\//\/code\/SSSS\//;
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: What i need to replace with "<TEXT>;"

Comment: That's not something you want to replace. It says to read lines from the filehandle by this name. Perhaps you want to modify the file name it's attached to, which is the second argument to the `open` call on the previous line.

Comment: @triplee

**I am getting error like this.**
    [root@web1 URLs]$ cat script.sh  
    file="/tmp/URLs/test.txt"  
    open(TEXT, "<file");  
    my @lines = <TEXT>;  
    close(TEXT);  
   
    foreach my $line (@lines) {  
    $line =~ s/\/catalogue\/([^\/]+)\/(?!(code\/|.+?\/code\/))/\/catalogue\/SSSS\//;  
    $line =~ s/\/code\/([^\/]+)\//\/code\/SSSS\//;  
    print $line;  
    }  
  
     [root@web1 URLs]$ ./script.sh  
    ./script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `TEXT,'  
    ./script.sh: line 2: `open(TEXT, "<file");'

Comment: You want `$file` in the `open`; it is trying to open a file named literally `file`. Also, this is a Perl script, not a `sh` script.

Comment: @Santhosh you are running the code as a `sh` script.
Put a shebang line something like `#!/usr/bin/perl` (the path to perl interpreter in your system) at the top of your script.

Comment: @tshiono I got it Thank you